# Brunch add animate.css

Tags: npm, animate.css, brunch

I am new to brunch and just want to add animate.css to one page.
I already installed animate.css via npm and added it to package.json.
My brunch-config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  npm: {
  globals: {
    $: 'jquery'
  },
  styles: {
    animate: ['css/animate.css']
  }
},

  files: {
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'libraries.js': /^(?!app\/)/,
      'app.js': /^app\//
    }
  },
    stylesheets: {joinTo: 'app.css'}
  }
}
```

No idea how to include animate.css to my page.
Any suggestions?

THX

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file is not *watched* by brunch. For a simple solution, just add the path manually to you stylesheets like this:

```
stylesheets: {
    joinTo: { 'app.css': [
        'path/to/animatie.css',   // include specific file
        /\.css$/                    // all files with .css extension
    ] }
}
```

Read more about the pattern matching in the docs: http://brunch.io/docs/config.html#pattern-matching